# Cannot find libiomp5.so when running code in Qt creator

Tags: openmp, icc

I'm testing my OpenMP code in Qt creator using intel compiler `icc`. When I run it in Qt creator, there's always an error `libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Then I checked the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, everything was fine. I also used `ldd` command to see the linked libraries.

```
libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.2.181/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00007fadada3a000)
```

As shown, the program was actually linked to that library, and I could even run it well in terminal directly. It was so strange since I build the whole project using Qt creator.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by myself finally. Just add the path of the library into `ld.so.conf`. Then run `ldconfig` to update the cache.